# The C key stopped working, any workaround to emulate 'Command + C'?

Tags: keyboard

On a macbook, the **`C`** key isn't working anymore, so i was wondering if there was a way to trigger the **`command + c`** shortcut other than pressing the **`command`** and **`C`** keys

Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you use a computer without a 'C' key? For that matter, how did you input this question?

Comment: "A" Macbook, OP said, not "this Macbook"  :)

Comment: I've seen people use Macs with several broken keys for years. What some can't stand, others just roll with.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Copy and paste. With the mouse. :)

Comment: Not to get too chatty, but at my first job, the terminal I used didn't have an <ENTER> key.  So, how long do you think it took me to break myself of the habit of pressing <CTRL-M>?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the Edit menu and select copy

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This page tells you how to pick a different keyboard shortcut for Copy: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13911

To address the larger issue of not having a C key anywhere else, you can use the [Keyboard Viewer](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13746) (search for it in Finder Help) to press any key that's malfunctioning when an external keyboard isn't convenient or at hand. Adding c to the special characters window might also work better for some than summoning the keyboard viewer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I completely understand the reason, but it's tragic that web pages are so impermanent that we resort to copy-pasting their contents on to other pages. Still, message received.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and easy:** 
Use `Right-Click`, or the trackpad `two-finger-click` gesture, or the `Control+Click` keyboard shortcut (all of which do the same thing effectively) to invoke a context menu on whatever you have selected, and you can choose Copy from the context menu.

**Also quick and easy:** 
Invoke the Edit menu from the keyboard and select Copy from there, as Maximus has proposed. Or go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` to create a new shortcut for Copy, as Nik M has helpfully proposed.

**Neither quick nor easy:**

If you enjoy Rube Goldbergian solutions, you will *love* this:

Change your keyboard layout to Dvorak. `System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources`. If you tick "Show input menu in menu bar" you can even get a lovely drop-down menu in the menu bar for fast switching between layouts. You can use standard QWERTY most of the time and switch to Dvorak when you need the C key.

But why switch back and forth? Just commit, and learn Dvorak for all your typing needs!

Dvorak puts the C on a key you haven't broken yet, and moves the—well, that letter after I and before K, you know the one—to where the C used to be.

And really, who *ever* uses that letter? You'll be totally fine without it.

Sincerely, your friend...

*facepalm* onathan

<sub>p.s. I jest. Do the first one. It's what I've always done in a broken-key situation.</sub>

Answer (score -5):

I believe the solution Apple recommends is to buy a new MacBook.

Comment: They might even replace the keyboard :-)

Comment: Hopefully the new computer would have a different keyboard, yes :)